# Serving http content on nfs mounted under docker

Tags: docker, nfs, selinux

my configuration is:
CentOS7 Atomic machine with a httpd-24-centos7 container
the http content is a nfs mounted volume.

I have been getting errors: "AH00686: cannot read directory for multi"

Yes... it is a SeLinux configuration to be set properly,
setting:

```
setsebool -P httpd_use_nfs on
```

did not help

It may save sombody hours that I've spent, 
what did help is:

```
setsebool -P virt_use_nfs on
```

Janusz

Comment: You should write [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52624608/#new-answer) instead of including the answer in the question.

Comment: may be You are right but rather tell me if it was usefull; we all look here for knowledge an solutions, right?